# The 'Drupal' way to query the database

Tags: database

I'm using the method below to query the database within a custom module but it doesn't seem to be the 'Drupal' way of doing things. Is there a better way?

```
$sql = "SELECT field1, field2 FROM {tablename} WHERE field3 = $var1 AND field4 = $var2";
$result = db_query($sql);
$num = $result->rowCount();
if ($num != null) {
  foreach($result as $line) {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

Comment: Check out [Entity Field Queries](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

welcome.

The only tweak needed I see is:

```
$sql = "SELECT field1, field2 FROM {tablename} WHERE field3 = :var1 AND field4 = :var2";
$result = db_query($sql, array(':var1' => $var1, ':var2' => $var2));
```

The method you've written your query allows for SQL-Injection -- using placeholders in the SQL helps to defend against this.

I invite you to read up on the [Database API](https://drupal.org/developing/api/database) documentation, specifically queries:

- [Result Sets](https://drupal.org/node/1251174)
- [Dynamic Queries](https://drupal.org/node/310075)
- [Static Queries](https://drupal.org/node/310072)